# Windows Encrypted Virtual Hard Drive but not Bitlocker or Truecrypt?

Tags: windows, windows-8, encryption

So if I want a virtual encrypted hard drive on my Windows 7 or 8 machine (i.e. an encrytped file that can be mounted like a hard drive) generally I would have used [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) for that. However it seems that TrueCrypt is being [discountinued/abandoned](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/05/true-goodbye-using-truecrypt-is-not-secure/), so: Are there any other decent alternatives?

Lets assume I don't want to use the built in Bitlocker because it *probably* has NSA backdoors and/or Microsoft backdoors etc.

Preferably something free and open-source. I've had a quick look round and there doesn't seem to be much else for Windows. Am I right?

Comment: Vote to close as a dupe of the multi platform question:http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4539/2313

Comment: @RoryAlsop Careful: Though I agree with you about the direction, that other question has already 3 close votes for being a duplicate on this, so we're in danger of creating a "loop" here ;)