# File-based encryption with virtual disk support for Windows

Tags: security

With TrueCrypt users advised to stop using the software, is there similar software that:

- supports virtual disk mounting from encrypted files
- offers plausible deniability via hidden volumes
- has been proven reliable enough for real-world use

A [related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt) discusses alternatives for whole-disk encryption but I need a solution for the multiple encrypted archives that are currently in use on my work systems, external hard-drives and flash drives.

I'm personally looking for Windows alternatives but Linux or multi-platform software might be useful for other users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to TrueCrypt?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt)

Comment: @mirabilos OP already mentioned that question and describes why it's *not* a duplicate: The linked one asks about *options for whole disk encryption*, while this one here asks for "containers" or *multiple encrypted archives*, as the OP states. I wouldn't count that a "duplicate", just a "relative" :)