# Crossplatform encrypted file container alt for TrueCrypt?

Tags: windows, osx, encryption

I use a TrueCrypt volume on a USB device to move a corpus of confidential files between a Mac OS 10.6.8 machine and a Win XP machine (both directions).  I have been using TrueCrypt 7.1a.

What if any alternatives to TrueCrypt do I have?  FOSS highly preferred.  That it support a **file container** is required (the file names are themselves confidential).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt

Comment: A "close relative", yes; but that is asking for *disk encryption,* and here OP asks for *file containers* – so it's not quite the same (though worth a look, as one of the solutions there might include this option as well). Also related: [File-based encryption with virtual disk support for Windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4572/185)

Answer (score 4):

[**VeraCrypt**](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) is a free, open source disk encryption software for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. VeraCrypt can create a virtual encrypted disk within a file or encrypt a partition or storage device.

VeraCrypt supports loading TrueCrypt volumes and partitions, both normal and hidden. In order to activate this, you have to check *TrueCrypt Mode* in the password prompt dialog.

#### Features

- Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
- Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
- Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed ([pre-boot authentication](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Encryption.html)).
- Encryption is automatic, real-time(on-the-fly) and transparent.
- [Parallelization](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Parallelization.html) and [pipelining](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Pipelining.html) allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.
- Encryption can be [hardware-accelerated](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hardware%20Acceleration.html) on modern processors.
- Provides [plausible deniability](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Plausible%20Deniability.html), in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password: [hidden volume](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hidden%20Volume.html) (steganography) and [hidden operating system](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hidden%20Operating%20System.html). VeraCrypt can hide an encrypted volume inside another VeraCrypt volume in such a way that it impossible to prove the second hidden volume exists (if the correct precautions are taken).
- More information about the features of VeraCrypt may be found in the [documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Documentation.html).

[image: VeraCrypt]