# A software that can encrypt contents of a USB flash drive

Tags: windows, usb, encryption

I have 3 remote site; each with a Windows workstation that is collecting data and writing it to a USB flash drive. Every week, a computer operator will rotate the USB flash drive and courier the drives back to head office where an analyst will analyse the data on the USB drive from a dedicated workstation

I'm looking for an encryption software that is capable of encrypting the USB flash drive; making the content of the USB flash drive accessible from via the remote workstation and the dedicated workstation in head office.

The software must have a password / encryption key mechanism in place that would be configured one time so that workstation with the same software and right key can encrypt and decrypt the data on the USB flash drive. The said password / encryption key can only be changed by the administrator.

Would prefer freeware or any commercial software that offers individual / per workstation licensing.

Comment: possible duplicate http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/5626/1925

Comment: If it is the same computer operator every time (or maybe two): have you considered buying USB drives that are designed especially for this and that need a fingerprint to access?