# What software could deny access to a USB Drive, with an encryption password?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, usb

I'm looking for software free or paid which would enable:

Upon connection of a USB drive protected by this software, require a correct password to be entered. And if the password entered is incorrect, access to the USB drive shouldn't be granted (due to encryption etc.).

But if the application protecting the contents of the USB drive for whatever reason wasn't activated or present, the files on the USB drive would remain encrypted etc.

Software protecting access to the USB drive should be completely stored on the USB drive, requiring no extra software on the side of the machine which the USB drive is connecting to.

**Security is a priority**

I would like this software to be compatible with Windows.

Comment: Do you want this software to be compatible with Windows and Linux? What do you mean by "without an encryption password" and "require a correct password to be entered"?

Comment: I've modified the title. I want this to be compatible with Windows and if the software can't be run the data on the USB drive shouldn't be accessible

Comment: ok, [possible dup](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/portable-encryption-for-usb-flash-drives)

Comment: You could just encrypt the drive using something like PGP and then just decrypt when you need to access your files

Answer (score 3):

The default windows **Bitlocker** program which is available in windows vista and up is just fine see

a detailed tutorial here
http://www.howtogeek.com/192894/how-to-set-up-bitlocker-encryption-on-windows/

and technical details of a the program here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/bitlocker-drive-encryption-overview

Comment: BitLocker is only available in the Professional or Enterprise Editions of Windows.