# OS agnostic solution for encrypting USB flash drives?

Tags: encryption, portable

I typically use "BitLocker to Go" but for encrypting and protecting my flash drives. However, that means I can't use them with my Macs, at least not without a [3rd-party program](https://www.m3datarecovery.com/mac-bitlocker/) (which isn't free and is less than ideal).

I was reading about LaCie Public Private, but it has since been end-of-life'd. Does anyone know of an encryption solution that:
- Works for both Windows & Mac (and ideally Linux as well)
- Is "client-less" meaning that it stores any obligatory software (such as the .EXE needed to decrypt the drive) on the drive itself, albeit in a separate partition? This is extremely important since the software manufacturer could stop supporting it at anytime.

Comment: [This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/portable-encryption-for-usb-flash-drives) only mentions Windows (and older versions at that), but some of the suggestions in the answers are cross-platform or available for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2):

[Veracrypt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeraCrypt) has clients for Windows, Linux, and macos, I'm pretty sure it can run as a "portable" app in most of them.

And it's FOSS, so even if "the software manufacturer could stop supporting it at anytime" someone else will just maintain or fork it, it's already a fork of TrueCrypt itself.