# portable veracrypt (alternative) without Admin-Privilege needs?

Tags: encryption, portable

I was looking for longer for a VeraCrypt / Alternative to encrypt my ThumbDrive in my Schools-Computers.
Basicly i have no admin rights there. Is there any alternative wich isn't a workaround - like a Local WebDav server?

I want to use my Portable BrowserInstallation in my USB-Drive and actually keep my cookies ^^

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

VeraCrypt's [own](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) portable installer (Windows > Portable version) does exactly that. Despite being in an installer form, it doesn't need administrative privileges: it exports the files into `VeraCrypt` directory.

You could have two partitions in your USB drive, the other being unecrypted and containing the VeraCrypt directory. Of course it's possible that the host operation system can compromise your installation, but you should not decrypt the volume on such a sucpicious device anyway.

Comment: That's incorrect. Even the portable version needs Admin permissions to [install the driver](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Using%20VeraCrypt%20Without%20Administrator%20Privileges.html). What could work is [SecurStick](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/5653/13298)