# What cost effective alternatives are there to Jetico BestCrypt?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, hard-disk

I'm currently assessing alternatives to Truecrypt, Veracypt and others (as discussed in the post [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt/24810#24810)). [Jetico BestCrypt](https://www.jetico.com/data-encryption) appears to be a viable paid competitor to options such as Bitlocker. It isn't however cost effective option.

The solution is intended to support Windows 10 devices that are either installed with the Home and Professional. Windows 10 Professional features Bitlocker however there is a desire to standardize on a common solution to simplify administration and support.

The software should also support the encryption of external devices such as portable hard disks.

What other options are there?

Comment: Why would you prefer to pay for encryption, when Veracrypt has been audited?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik - The rationale at evaluating a product such as Jetico is because Veracrypt isn't a fully featured. Additionally, it is intended to be deployed to devices used by those that are not technically adept.

Comment: If you're willing to pay for encryption, why would you not just upgrade everything to Windows 10 Pro?  You get a lot of other useful features by doing so, and can then just use the solution built into Windows.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgarn - The cost of an upgrade isn't limited to purchasing Windows 10 Pro only. This would include the cost of upgrading the hardware since the devices don't support TPM. Yes, the is the opportunity to leverage a password/pin however it limits Bitlocker's capabilities. Secondly, there are users that are located elsewhere. The ability to upgrade the devices would not be an option.